# Converting weird NBA data structure into a pandas dataframe from an API

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to convert this string into a pandas dataframe where each value before the colon is a header and the next value is put in the column. This is what the data structure looks like:

```
{"data":[{"id":47179,"date":"2019-01-30T00:00:00.000Z","home_team":{"id":2,"abbreviation":"BOS","city":"Boston","conference":"East","division":"Atlantic","full_name":"Boston Celtics","name":"Celtics"},"home_team_score":126,"period":4,"postseason":false,"season":2018,"status":"Final","time":" ","visitor_team":{"id":4,"abbreviation":"CHA","city":"Charlotte","conference":"East","division":"Southeast","full_name":"Charlotte Hornets","name":"Hornets"},"visitor_team_score":94},{"id":48751,"date":"2019-02-09T00:00:00.000Z","home_team":{"id":2,"abbreviation":"BOS","city":"Boston","conference":"East","division":"Atlantic","full_name":"Boston Celtics","name":"Celtics"}}
```

This sting I am converting has hundreds of games but I stop pasting after two. What is this data structure called and how can I quickly move it to a dataframe?

Comment: looks like json - https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: this is a very common format to store data. python has a library for it, just do `import json`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like json, but it's not structured in a very useful way; everything is under the "data" key. To get it into a DataFrame, use a combination of Python's `json` module and `pandas.normalize_json()`.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data_string = """{"data":[{"id":47179,"date":"2019-01-30T00:00:00.000Z",
"home_team":{"id":2,"abbreviation":"BOS","city":"Boston",
"conference":"East","division":"Atlantic","full_name":"Boston Celtics",
"name":"Celtics"},"home_team_score":126,"period":4,"postseason":false,
"season":2018,"status":"Final","time":" ","visitor_team":{"id":4,
"abbreviation":"CHA","city":"Charlotte","conference":"East",
"division":"Southeast","full_name":"Charlotte Hornets","name":"Hornets"},
"visitor_team_score":94},{"id":48751,"date":"2019-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
"home_team":{"id":2,"abbreviation":"BOS","city":"Boston",
"conference":"East","division":"Atlantic","full_name":"Boston Celtics",
"name":"Celtics"}}]}"""

raw_data = json.loads(data_string)

df = pd.json_normalize(raw_data['data'])
```

There is a lot of redundant information about the teams. Look at "home_team" for the two games, the information is the same.  You could pull all the team data into a separate DataFrame and use the team "id" or "abbreviation" in the DataFrame with all the games.

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://free-nba.p.rapidapi.com/stats"

querystring = {"page": "0", "per_page": "25"}

headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "your_key",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "free-nba.p.rapidapi.com"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

data = response.json()

# Convert JSON response to DataFrame
df = pd.json_normalize(data['data'])

print(df)
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.